# Sqla flask two ForeignKey the same table

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a table "ProductVariant"

```
class ProductVariant(sqla.Model, ExtendMixin, ResourcesMixin):

 vendor_id = sqla.Column(
        sqla.Integer,
        sqla.ForeignKey('vendors.id'),
        nullable=True)
    decorator_id = sqla.Column(
        sqla.Integer,
        sqla.ForeignKey('vendors.id'),
        nullable=True)
```

and i cant understand how i need create a back ref in the table "Vendor"

```
class Vendor(sqla.Model, ExtendMixin):
 pv_vendors = sqla.relationship(
        'ProductVariant',
        backref='vendor')
    pv_decorators = sqla.relationship(
        'ProductVariant',
        backref='vendor')
```

i have an error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Vendor.pv_vendors - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.`

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'vendors' and 'product_variants'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify which foreign key to reference with [backref](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.backref), since it's ambiguous

```py
class ProductVariant(sqla.Model, ExtendMixin, ResourcesMixin):

    vendor_id = sqla.Column(
        sqla.Integer,
        sqla.ForeignKey('vendors.id'),
        nullable=True)

    decorator_id = sqla.Column(
        sqla.Integer,
        sqla.ForeignKey('vendors.id'),
        nullable=True)


class Vendor(sqla.Model, ExtendMixin):
    pv_vendors = sqla.relationship(
        'ProductVariant',
        backref=backref('vendor', foreign_keys="ProductVariant.vendor_id"))

    pv_decorators = sqla.relationship(
        'ProductVariant',
        backref=backref('decorator', foreign_keys="ProductVariant.decorator_id"))
```